# browser compatibality issue for scrolling div

Tags: html

I am facing an issue with browser compatibility. my code works fine in mozilla, IE6 but not in IE7. The code is for genaerating a scroolable div in the page.

```
    <html>
 <style rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
#scrolldiv
 {
    overflow: auto; max-height: 200px;
    height:expression(this.scrollHeight>199?"200px":"auto");
 }
</style>

<div  id="scrolldiv" name="scrolldiv">
            <table align="center" border=0>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tr><td>testdata1</td></tr>

                    <tr><td>testdata2</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata3</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata1</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata2</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata3</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata1</td></tr>

                    <tr><td>testdata2</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata3</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata1</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata2</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata3</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata1</td></tr>

                    <tr><td>testdata2</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata3</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata1</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata2</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testdata3</td></tr>
                </table>

            </td></tr>
            </table>
</div>
</html>
```

Please advise

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please use code-formatting by clicking the {}-symbol next time. i fixed this for you.

Comment: What, specifically, isn't working?

Comment: Hi Katie, the scrolling div is generating fine but it appears at the end of the page instead in the top of page, u can check this if u test my sample code above in IE7/IE8

Comment: If it is so urgent, then use [conditional CSS](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) that adjusts your UI for IE7.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you've disabled JavaScript in your IE7. IEs css-expressions are evaluated as javascript, so in this case it won't work.

please also note that you should [avoid css-expressions](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_6/) whenever possible.

Comment: Is there anybody here to give a solution?

Comment: If you are viewing a page in IE through a **local** URL (c:\something\file.html) rather than through a web server (http://web.int/file.html), then IE will disable all scripts.  
I viewed the OP's code through a web server in IE7 and IE8, and saw the div displayed at the top of the page.  When viewed locally, the div did not display as expected.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#scrolldiv
 {
    height:auto !important;
    overflow: auto; max-height: 200px;
    _height:200px;
 }
```

Comment: I tested this fix and it worked for me - showing the div at the top of the page even when I viewed the page in IE through a local URL.  This was likely because replacing the expression height setting with CSS made it so that there was no script that IE felt the need to disable.

Answer (score 0):

If that is all your markup, you are missing a doctype and are in 'quirks mode'. Add this as your first line: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` Then let's see where things stand.